# Scope store price value not saved

Tags: magento2, price, multistore, scope

We have a multi-store instance where if you set the price of a product in any of the stores that are not default, save it, then a success message will be shown, but the price is unchanged and the “Use Default” checkbox is still checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue happens because `admin_system_config_changed_section_catalog` (`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Observer/SwitchPriceAttributeScopeOnConfigChange.php`) is not called at that point when saving the product.

If you use the `bin/magento config:set catalog/price/scope 1` command, again this event is never called and thus will not update the price.

The solution to this is to change a random unimportant setting in the catalog section and then the observer should be called.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!